# Program works on onlineGDB compiler but has logic errors when compiled with MinGW

Tags: c

I've written the following program on a online compiler called onlineGDB as a single block. On this website it works perfectly but after I split the modules into separate source files and compiled it with MinGW it's getting stuck in the first loop (validateInput).

```
bool validateInput(float input) {
    if (input < 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}

int main() {
    float salaries[SIZE] = { 0 };
    float newSalaries[SIZE] = { 0 };
    int i = 0;

    float *salriesPtr = salaries;
    float *newSalariesPtr = newSalaries;

    bool exit = false;
    bool inputDone = false;

    welcome();

    do {
        do {
            salaries[i] = getInput();
            inputDone = validateInput (salaries[i]);
            newSalaries[i] = payRise (salaries[i]);
            i++;
        } while (inputDone == false);

        output(salriesPtr, newSalariesPtr);
        exit = exitProgram ();
    } while (exit == false);

    return 0;
}
```

The program is supposed to keep adding values to the array until a negative number is input. This works on the online compiler but is creating an infinite loop when compiled with MinGW.

EDIT: Here is MVCE

```
#define SIZE 100

bool validateInput (float input)
{

    if (input < 0)
    return true;

    return false;
}

int getInput ()
{

  int input;

  printf ("Enter salary: ");

  scanf ("%d%*c", &input);

  return (input);
}

int main () {

  float salaries[SIZE] = { 0 };

  bool inputDone = false;   

  do
    {

      salaries[1] = getInput ();

      inputDone = validateInput (salaries[1]);

    }
      while (inputDone == false);

  return 0;
}
```

And the header file. All the other source files are just the functions copied into there own .c file.

```
#ifndef MAIN
#define MAIN

void welcome();
float getInput();
float payRise(float salary);
void output(float* salaries, float* newSalaries);
bool validateInput(float input);
bool exitProgram();

#endif
```

Comment: So there are two differences, Mingw instead of online AND code changes. What makes you think that the code changes are NOT responsible for the changed behavior? Does Mingw cause logic errors when compiling the unchanged code, too? Please reduce the unknowns by trying this.

Comment: Consider showing the code change, i.e. showing both versions of the code (each as a MCVE). That will allow looking for the problem in the changes.

Comment: Please post some [MCVE]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mate can't believe I didn't think of that haha. It's the code, but I still don't understand why it's happening as the only change I've made is putting the modules in separate source files.

Comment: I bet "only split into two files" is not the only thing you did. At least not cleanly... No insult meant. Show both versions and people here will probably help you find the hidden difference. Please make two MCVEs.

Comment: Alright will do. I'm still a newbie, what things would you suggest to be removed to make it readable and still function?

Comment: the version for MinGW and MVCE are completely different

Comment: It's the minimal, functional example of where the issue is occurring as described in the page for MCVE. Is that not what It's supposed to be?

Comment: `bool`, `true` and `false` make me think that you are not compiling C source

Comment: @Mathieu OP probably uses `stdbool.h`

Comment: I'm using stdbool, I'm still a newbie could this be causing the issues?

Comment: @C.Deighton no, to use bool is good

Comment: @C.Deighton the error is between the declaration and the definition of _getInput_, see my answer

Comment: @bruno That actually fixed it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem probably comes because you declare *getInput* as returning a *float* but its definition returns an *int*

when you do `salaries[i] = getInput();` the code make a *float* from an *int* but because it is already a *float* the conversion is wrong, and after the test of the sign is wrong too

Out of that I strongly encourage you to test the result of *scanf* to be sure a valid input was done, else you definitively not get a value value because the invalid value is never bypassed

Answer (score 0):

You should test the return of `scanf`.

Indeed, if you don't enter anything, the value of `input` stay uninitialized and that could explain the infinite loop.

```
int getInput ()
{
    int input;
    printf ("Enter salary: ");
    if (2 == scanf ("%d%*c", &input))
        return input;

    else 
        /* if scanf was not able to read one integer and one char, return a negative value */
        return -1;
}
```